# How do I query how many worksheets I have in a Google Sheet via Sheets API in Android

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Using the Sheets API in Android, how would I be able to find all the sheets I have in a spreadsheet ? Don't see anything straightforward in the API docs, but maybe there is a clever WA to get those.

to illustrate, in the below example, I would like to get the 5 labels of the 5 worksheets:

[image]

---

[EDIT] Follow-up question (thanks Trevor), showing my (lack of) Java skills:

So this way I can get the title of the first Worksheet:

```
Spreadsheet responseSpreadSheet = this.mService.spreadsheets().get(sheetsID).execute();
String First_Sheet_Title = responseSpreadSheet.getSheets().get(0).getProperties().getTitle();
```

Out of curiosity, why doesn't this approach work ? It doesn't let me apply the 'getProperties' method on the single sheet I assume to get back from 'get(0). I'm sure it's some basic Java thing I'm missing:

```
List responseSheets = responseSpreadSheet.getSheets();
String First_Sheet_Title = responseSheets.get(0).getProperties().getTitle();
```

Also, is there an easy way to get all worksheet names in a single line ? Right now I plan to iterate over the list/array I get back from getSheets, is there a way to apply the 'getTitle' directly on it to get back the list of worksheet names ? (Hope that question is somewhat meaningful)

Comment: in the API docs it shows that when you [GET a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) the response body will contain an instance of [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet) which contains an array `sheets` which are all of the [Sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Sheet) in the Spreadsheet. Each Sheet has a [SheetProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#SheetProperties) object which contains the name.

Comment: awesome, perfect pointer. If you file this as an answer, I can accept it and also post some of the code that makes it work. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the API docs it shows that when you [GET a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) the response body will contain an instance of a Spreadsheet.

The [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet) contains an array **sheets** which are all of the Sheets in the Spreadsheet

```
{
  "spreadsheetId": string,
  "properties": {
    object(SpreadsheetProperties)
  },
  "sheets": [
    {
      object(Sheet)
    }
  ],
  "namedRanges": [
    {
      object(NamedRange)
    }
  ],
  "spreadsheetUrl": string,
}
```

Each [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Sheet) has a **SheetProperties** object:

```
{
  "properties": {
    object(SheetProperties)
  },
  "data": [
    {
      object(GridData)
    }
  ],
  "merges": [
    {
      object(GridRange)
    }
  ],
  "conditionalFormats": [
    {
      object(ConditionalFormatRule)
    }
  ],
  "filterViews": [
    {
      object(FilterView)
    }
  ],
  "protectedRanges": [
    {
      object(ProtectedRange)
    }
  ],
  "basicFilter": {
    object(BasicFilter)
  },
  "charts": [
    {
      object(EmbeddedChart)
    }
  ],
  "bandedRanges": [
    {
      object(BandedRange)
    }
  ],
}
```

The [SheetProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#SheetProperties) object contains a **title** field which is the label you're looking for:

```
{
  "sheetId": number,
  "title": string,
  "index": number,
  "sheetType": enum(SheetType),
  "gridProperties": {
    object(GridProperties)
  },
  "hidden": boolean,
  "tabColor": {
    object(Color)
  },
  "rightToLeft": boolean,
}
```